# How to override onPrepareOptionsMenu() in the fragment of an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity A in which I have a framelayout, in that I am replacing a list fragment with another fragment which shows the detail of list when I click an item on the list!!
I want to override the onPrepareOptionsMenu() in this fragment but not able to do that as activity got crashed everytime on the main activity's onPrepareOptionsMenu()!!

any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you share the log entries of that crash

Comment: show us some code and logcat

Comment: @Panther thanks for reminding, if I have asked the question I have the responsibility to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution actually I was not calling  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) thus it is not forwarding the call to fragment's onPrepare.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen() && (detailFragment!=null && detailFragment.isVisible())) {
            setActionBarTitleView();

    }
   else if(!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
    {

            menu.removeItem(R.id.action_share);
    }
  return  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu` on the fragment to indicate that it wants to participate on the menu construction.